# OAMutableURLRequest: signature invalide

Tags: ios, json, oauth

I am developing an app which required to call API with OAuth1.0.

I can successfully get access token. But when I try to post Json data at that time. It give me error.
Code for post JSON data with request.

```
-(void)sampleRequest2{
    // create URL from string
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://myurl"];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Json" ofType:@"rtf"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];


    // create url request
    OAMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc]  initWithURL:url
                                                   consumer:consumer
                                                      token:accessToken
                                                      realm:nil
                                          signatureProvider:nil] autorelease];
    OARequestParameter* callbackParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_callback" value:callback];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:callbackParam,nil]];
    [urlRequest prepare];


    __weak NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[data length]];

    // Create entire body
    NSMutableData* dataRequestBody = [NSMutableData data];

     NSString* boundary = @"----IMAGE_UPLOAD";
    [dataRequestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [dataRequestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Length: %@\r\n\r\n",postLength] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [dataRequestBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [dataRequestBody appendData:data];
    [dataRequestBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:dataRequestBody];
 OADataFetcher *dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc]init];
    [dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self completionBlock:^(OAServiceTicket *ticket, NSMutableData *data) {
        if (data == nil) {

        }else{
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"JSON Response: %@",json);
        }
    }
                          failedBlock:^{
                              NSLog(@"Failed");
                          }];
}
```

Error in response :

```
JSON Response: {
    messages =     {
        error =         (
                        {
                code = 401;
                message = "oauth_problem=signature_invalid";
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution after searching by two days.

I need to pass Signature Provider at a time of creating request.

```
 OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url consumer:consumer  token:accessToken realm:realm signatureProvider:[[OAPlaintextSignatureProvider alloc] init]];
```

For passing JSON data.

```
[request setHTTPBody:[strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

So, finale code is..

```
 OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url consumer:consumer  token:accessToken realm:realm signatureProvider:[[OAPlaintextSignatureProvider alloc] init]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:callbackParam,releamParam, nil]];

    [request setValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  NSString *strJson = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"{\"products\" : [  {\"qty\" : \"1\",\"product\" : \"404\",\"super_attribute\" : {\"180\" : \"80\",                                               \"92\" : \"17\" } }]}"];
  [request setHTTPBody:[strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 OADataFetcher* dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

    [dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request delegate:self completionBlock:^(OAServiceTicket *ticket, NSMutableData *data) {
        if (data == nil) {

        }else{        
            NSLog(@"header: %@",request.allHTTPHeaderFields);
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            NSLog(@"JSON Response: %@",json);
        }
    }
                          failedBlock:^{
                              NSLog(@"Failed");
                          }];
```